# Does filter() produce a db hit in django

Tags: python, django

I am not really familiar with django but have to do some small work on existing code. I am trying to limit the db hits and I was wondering which of the two ways produces the least amount of hits (if there is a difference at all).

1:

```
points1 = select_related(a,b).filter(filter1)
points2 = select_related(a,b).filter(filter2)
```

2:

```
points = select_related(a,b)
points1 = points.filter(filter1)
points2 = points.filter(filter2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Querysets are lazy, they won't hit the db until they are [evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated).

In this case, none of the statements evaluate the queryset, so there won't  be any difference.

Comment: So when I add a line saying eval = list(points1) + list(points2) it will hit the db twice in both cases?

Comment: Yes, that would hit the db twice. The results will be cached, so if you use `points1` or `points2` after they are evaluated, it won't hit the db again.